# Mysql. Query to insert data into a table related to another

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert

I'm new in sql. I have doubt. Let's say that I have two tables. One is called user and the other order.

```
User
User_Id - name - email

Order
Order_id - product - User_id
```

What query should I use to insert a new order in the order table with the User_id field related to the User_id from the user table(an existing user)

Eg:

```
Order_id - product - User_id
1a - plate - 1
2a - car - 3
3a - bike - 1
```

Comment: First of all, you should get a book, read and try. Only when you have tried all that and still fail, then you come here and ask.

Comment: There are countless tutorials on the internet.  Just did a 5 second search and came up with this detailed explanation. http://www.sql-tutorial.com/relations-keys-normalization-sql-tutorial/

Comment: @allingeek  - If you had taken 10 seconds instead of 5 you would have seen this link does not answer the question. It merely explains about normalisation. The OP's tables already are normalised. They were asking how to insert data in the orders table whilst ensuring that the correct user id gets passed. This is a very good question, as Vaandu's clear answer shows. Although theirs is a good solution it assumes that NAME is a unique value in the user table from which the user_id may be found. But if NAME is unique then the table user wouldn't need a user_id in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `name` or `email` of the user, you can try this. If USER has a composite primary key on `user_id` and `name` columns, it will work without any issues. Better to keep foreign key relationship on user_id column of `ORDER` also.

Example has NAME column, you can try with email column also.

```
INSERT INTO ORDER (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT, USER_ID)
VALUES (1a, 'plate', (SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE NAME = 'Existing user'));
```

EDIT:

I have worked on Oracle sql only. After your comment, found this link.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

If you have defined AUTO_INCREMENT on order_id column, you don't need to pass value.

```
INSERT INTO ORDER (PRODUCT, USER_ID)
VALUES ('plate', (SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE NAME = 'Existing user'));
```

Comment: If the order_id increments automatically I dont jeed to pass any value right?

Answer (score 0):

you use the standard sql insert.

```
insert into Order (Order_id, product, User_id) values ("3a", "bike", 1)
```

If your tables are set up property, there will be a foreign key restriction on the `User_id` field, so if you try to insert an order but don't reference a valid person, mysql will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT order (Order_id, product, User_id) VALUES (1a,plate,1)
```

The foreign key has nothing to do with the sql used in the insert it should have been set up when the table was created or via an ALTER TABLE query after it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Relationships between tables are defined when you create the table, using the FOREIGN KEY.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    UserId int primary key
);

CREATE TABLE Orders(
    OrderId int primary key,
    UserId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserId)
);
```

Then you do a simple insert like:

```
INSERT INTO ORDER(OrderId, UserId) VALUES(1, 5);
```

Take a look at the documentation for foreign key constraints here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html.

Comment: I understood. My doubt is when I create an order. How can refer that order with a specific user. Should I have to code the userid manually or make a select, like vanathi said?